# Category link not working in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <div class="panel">
    <h2><%=link_to post.title, post %></h2>
    <p><%=link_to post.category.try(:name), category %></p>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Post belongs_to to category, category has many post,

I got error

```
  undefined local variable or method `category' for #<#<Class:0x0000010588c6a0>:0x000001097205d8><p>
  <%=link_to post.category.try(:name), category %></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to link to the associated object. Remember, you have available to you the `post` object. So to find that `post` objects `category`, you need to call `post.category`

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="panel">
    <h2><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
    <p><%= link_to post.category.try(:name), post.category %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Anytime. Glad to help.